# Been editing Tumblr theme, now its giving a non-HTTPS after already saving

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

So I have been making small tweaks to a tumblr theme I installed directly from tumblrs free themes list. I was editing the theme and adding in a simple text line 'twst' to areas to try and ID where elements were. There was one element I wanted to remove that being the tag title for pages.
I found it. A simple
h2 class="tagtitle customfont">{Tag}</h2
biz. I went to remove just that line.

But now the page is giving me this dumb
"Un oh! We couldn't save your theme. Looks like your custom theme references assets from non-HTTPS Urls. Please try again using only HTTPS Urls."

Like uhh.. wut? It's been saving just fine up until now, just adding tags like for descriptions on pages.
[Now I'm stuck with 'twst' saved to the page and it won't let me edit it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngprj.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLFP2.png
So now the text is stuck on a page it let me save just moments beforehand. What gives?!

It also seems the update preview is now getting stuck. It wasn't before. Does that have anything to do with it? Is it a false error?

Comment: Tumblr stopped support for http and resources loaded over http some time ago. This would only affect you once you went in and edited your theme (if you had any http links in there). Most people advise just updating the links to https, especially for third party resources. If you are trying to serve your own content it has to be from an https domain. Tumblr used to have a resource uploader for this purpose but it has long gone. Dropbox also used to be viable, but they stopped the file sharing option. Maybe google sites might work